# twitteR package for R authentication: error 401

Tags: r, authentication, twitter

Hy everyone/anyone and thank you for considering it!
I'm stuck at the final stage of `twitteR` package authentication. After a successful `cred$handshake` as I'm trying to end up the authentication with `setup_twitter_oauth`, the program keeps throwing the following message:

```
Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = 
self$params$permission) : client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

Any idea what this could be and how could I get around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure the precise source of your error, and I had used this package about 2 months ago. I ran into errors doing the handshake as well.

To work-around, I avoided the explicit `handshake` by using `setup_twitter_oauth` directly.

```
consumerKey <- "[your Twitter consumer key]"
consumerSecret <- "[your Twitter consumer secret]"
accessToken <- "[your Twitter access token]"
accessTokenSecret <- "[your Twitter access token secret]"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
```

This seemed to work for me. The various OAuth parameters come from Twitter. I wrote up how to do that here: [Newborn app using Twitter and R](http://rayli.net/blog/data/newborn-app-using-twitter-and-r-data-analysis/).

The complete R source code is on BitBucket (the stuff at the bottom is probably most relevant): [newborn-app.R](https://bitbucket.org/dailymorn/newborn-app/src/8142076bc5db5b34f84b02820cf86b07dbefaa31/newborn-app.R?at=default).

Comment: Indeed, the handshake skipping is the way to go! The updated twitteR guide says the setup_twitter_oauth function wraps the OAuth authentication handshake functions from the httr package for a twitteR session. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That worked for me too. The current vignette says to just use `setup_twitter_oauth( 'one', 'two')`, but using all four worked.