# Retrieve a Users Dashboard in Tumblr with R and TumblR. Oauth Issues

Tags: r, oauth, tumblr

I am trying to use the TumblR package in R to set up the Oauth Authentication to Retrieve a user's dashboard using the second example in 
[tumblR documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tumblR/tumblR.pdf)
However I get the following error, it seems that using twitter others have been able to use a different function to get around this, but I am not finding the same function available for Tumblr. 
See [twitter package for R authentication: error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504484)
My code

```
consumer_key <- OKey
consumer_secret <- SKey
appname <- App_name
tokenURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
accessTokenURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/acces_token'
authorizeURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize'
app <- oauth_app(appname , consumer_key, consumer_secret)
endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(tokenURL, authorizeURL, accessTokenURL)
token <- oauth1.0_token(endpoint, app)
```

The error I am receiving is the following.

> Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission =
>   self$params$permission,  :  Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

I am using R version 3.4.0 and Rstudio Version 1.1.463

Answer (score 0):

Reply from the package maintainer.

I'm sorry for the delay in the reply, I'm currently out for work.

The problem you reported depends on the change in the http protocol. The API URLs are now passed to https.
You can use

```
tokenURL <- 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
accessTokenURL <- 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/acces_token'
authorizeURL <- 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize'
```

I realized it only thanks to your report.
During the Christmas holidays, I plan to arrange the package.

If you have other evidence, let me know.